# VBA sub not entering functions

Tags: excel, vba

I created the below functions in different sheets in my Excel workbook and they are all executed by a sub. However when I start the sub it doesn't access the functions and directly skips the `If` statements.

Sheet1 functions:

```
Public Function ndg(row As Range) As Integer
    ndg = Range("b" & row).Value    
End Function

Function Checkispraticaforeclosure(row As Range)
   Dim ndga As Integer
   Dim rowindex As Integer
   ndga = ndg(row)
   rowindex = Sheet6.findrownumberndg(ndga)

   If Sheet6.ispositionforeclosure(rowindex) = True Then
       row.Cells(33) = Sheet6.getforeclosurecode(rowindex)
       Checkispraticaforeclosure = True
   Else
       Checkispraticaforeclosure = False
   End If
End Function

Sub insertcode(row As Range)
    Dim ndga As Integer
    Dim rowindex As Integer
    ndga = ndg(row)
    rowindex = Sheet6.findrownumberndg(ndga)

    If Sheet6.ispositionforeclosure(rowindex) = False Then    
        row.Cells(33) = "ok"
    End If
End Sub
```

Sheet6 functions:

```
Public Function findrownumberndg(ndg As Integer) As Integer
    Set foundcell = Sheet6.Range("a:a").Find(ndg, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then
        findrownumberndg = 0
    Else
        findrownumberndg = foundcell.row
    End If
End Function

Public Function ispositionforeclosure(row As Integer) As Boolean
    If Range("D" & row).Value = "Foreclosure procedure" Then
        ispositionforeclosure = True
    Else
        ispositionforeclosure = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function getforeclosurecode(row As Integer)    
    getforeclosurecode = Range("f" & row).Value
End Function
```

Execute sub:

```
Public Function sheet1lastrow()
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).row
End Function

Sub masterinsertcode()
    For x = 6 To ThisWorkbook.sheet1lastrow()
        Dim checked
        checked = False
        Dim currentrow As Range
        Set currentrow = Sheet1.Rows(x)

        checked = Sheet1.Checkispraticaforeclosure(currentrow)

        If checked = False Then
            Sheet1.insertcode (currentrow)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I am unsure why the execute sub doesn't enter in the checks I created and directly goes to `End Sub`.

Comment: What does `ThisWorkbook.sheet1lastrow()` return?

Comment: Hi this returns the last row number of the the sheet where the codes are meant to be inserted. so the sub starts at row six until the last row returned by that function.

Comment: What actual number does it return when you run `masterinsertcode` and it goes straight to `End Sub`?

Comment: it returns 60 as last row number

Comment: Then it wouldn't go straight to `End Sub`. It would enter the `For` loop and called `Sheet1.Checkispraticaforeclosure`. How do you know that does not happen?

Comment: well i know cause i put a breakpoint on the For and start clicking f8 and I see it enters the ThisWorkbook.sheet1lastrow() returning a 60 as last row but then it directly goes to end sub.

Comment: If you put the breakpoint *on* the `For`, then yes, it will only be hit once. Put the breakpoint inside the `For`.

Comment: if it goes directly to end sub putting the breakpoint inside the for wont stop anything cause theres nothing to breakpoint in there. its as if the arguments in the functions are not working properly but i cant figure out what exactly.

Comment: Don't you need to declare the return type of `Checkispracticaforeclosure()` ?

Comment: Hi @nacroid i just added dim checked as boolean to the sub but still just racing through to end sub. thanks anyways

Comment: When the breakpoint at For is hit, what are the value of ThisWorkbook.sheet1lastrow() **on that very point in your code**? If it is greater than or equal to 6 the for loop should run unless you have a stray On Error Resume Next somewhere

Comment: So at that very point the value of thisworkbook.sheet1lastrow is 60 so the for should run. but i dont see an error not being accounted for in the functions so why does it go straight to end sub.

Comment: I don't believe that. I think you are leaving out some crucial information about your code. Can you define a variable, say lastRow and assign it to ThisWorkbook.sheet1lastrow() just before the for loop? Stop as before (after the assignment) and tell us the value of lastRow

Comment: I mean your Function `Checkispraticaforeclosure(row As Range)`. There is not return type declared.

Comment: @peakpeak  thanks alot. the problem was the sheet1lastrow function. I accidentally defined the return value of the function with a different name. Haha a studpid mistake.

Comment: That's what F8 is for ... :)

Comment: You need `Option Explicit` in your code to prevent mistakes like that